# How to improve paralelized computing in AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, mpi

I am using mpi4py and MPICH (installed with conda) to parallelize the training of a reinforcement learning system across several CPUs ( using an AWS EC2 instance, namely, a c5.x12) with Ubuntu. I have benchmarked the performance and the amount of training per unit of time increases 30% (when 5 processes are used) with respect to the training with one single process. However, when I use 5 processes in my local computer I get an increase in the amount of training per unit of time of 300% with respect to the training with one single process.

In my computer I use Windows and Microsoft MPI, which I think is based on MPICH, so what can cause this performance difference? How can I get the best from AWS?

Comment: make sure MPI tasks are correctly pinned to non overlapping **physical** cores (otherwise you end up doing some kind of time sharing). How many sockets on your PC vs AWS? Also how does the CPU on your computer compare to the one in AWS? keep in slower cpus mean higher scalability.

Comment: We are newbies on this, could you recommend us any guide, reference or keywords to look for info lo learn enough to be capable to deal with your first sentence? Should we jump to other technologies like Hadoop/Spark? AWS have one socket with 24 CPUs with 2 threads each (48 * two machines = 98 threads) of Intel Xeon Cascade Lake with turbo frequency at 3,6GHz. Our CPU is one socket I7-8750H 6 cores with 12 threads in total (12 threads).